# App is getting forced stopped when i add admob ads

Tags: admob

I have tested my app and it works fine. But when I try to add my AdMob ads in it the app is stopping.app is not opening it gets forced stopped. And when I remove the AdMob ads the app is working properly

Comment: Please provide us some code.

Comment: I am a beginner.and i am creating a webview app for my blogger blog

Comment: Okay that's fine. Have you implemented admob code?

Comment: yes i have implemented .but can you tell me in details

Comment: Please add that code in the question.

Comment: can i show the picture of my gardle file

Comment: Please don't do that. You can check out how to [format a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then add gradle and JAVA code to question.

Comment: I have created a new project and i cant paste the ads in that too i will show the codes

Comment: Send me code at gouravkhunger18@gmail.com